# Comparator is removing duplicate objects from treemap

Tags: java

I'm working on a highscore system that reads from a file line-by-line and adds all lines into a treemap, sorts the treemap and adds the scores and names into a new file, highest score being at the top.

I've gotten the system close but for some unknown reason the code is removing duplicate entries, for example, i have 3 scores.

1 : Sander

1 : Sander

2 : Mark

Printing my treemap would look like this:

[image]

I would like the code to show Sander twice.

I've been stuck for quite some time and would appriciate some help, here is my code:

```
public void sortScores() throws IOException {
    File input = new File("scores.txt");
    File output = new File("outputscores.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    String aLine;
    while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] scoreAndName = aLine.split(" : ");
        int score1 = Integer.parseInt(scoreAndName[0]);
        String name1 = scoreAndName[1];
        unsortMap1.put(score1, name1);
    }
    Map<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(
            new Comparator<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                    if (o1 >= o2) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }

            });
    treeMap.putAll(unsortMap1);
    System.out.println(treeMap);
}
```

Comment: "for some unknown reason the code is removing duplicate entries" - yes, maps do that. You should probably go read up on what the Map interface actually promises.

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen the wrong collection type.

A `Map<Integer, String>` will store only one `String` value for any possible `Integer`.  So given a score (e.g. `1`) it can store a single name.  Not the same name multiple times.

It appears that you are trying to sort records representing scores.  To do that, you are going to need to create a custom class whose instances represent the records.

You can sort the records a number of ways:

- Put them into an array use `Arrays.sort`
- Put them into a list and use `Collections.sort`
- Implement your own sort algorithm.  (Not recommended.  It is better not to waste your time "reinventing the wheel".)

You will either need to implement a `Comparator` to order the records<sup>1</sup>, or make your record class implement `Comparable`.

For more details, please read the respective javadocs.

---

But you *cannot* use a `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` (or any other `Map` or `Set` implementations) for this.  Your records are not unique, and those data structures will remove duplicates<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - From Java 8, the `Comparator` interface has some static helper methods for creating comparators; e.g. `Comparator.comparingInt()`.</sup>

<sup>2 - Not strictly true.  You could do this if your records had a 3rd field containing a unique identifier which you used as a tie-breaker in the comparator.  Or you could use a `Map<YouRecord, Integer>`, where the integer represents a count of records that are "equal".</sup>

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the way Map is supposed to work. From [documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

`put(key, value)` replace the old value with the new one.

While you can make it work using `Map<Integer, List<String>>` (for example), that's cumbersome and doesn't look clean. [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is a better data structure for this task.

I would define a class Score, use it to populate the list, and sort it with a custom comparator. You could also make Score implement Comparable instead of using a Comparator.

Here's an example that uses Comparator.comparingInt().

```
List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();

scores.add(new Score(1, "Name")); //adding an element

scores.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Score::getScore)); //sorting

class Score {
    private final int score;
    private final String name;

    Score(int score, String name) {
        this.score = score;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```